# jQuery Easing Tutorial

Tags: jquery, menu, effect

I'm developing a menu and need to incorporate a jquery easing effect into the sub menu. The submenu is a horizontal dropline menu.

Here's the HTML and CSS for it if you're interested in looking at it. They are both not completed so don't mind my mess :)

Preview http://wilwaldon.com/easing/easingmenu.html

I've already Googled but didn't find anything for a total noobie like myself.

THANK YOU!

Comment: First off, you need to only have 1 copy of jQuery. Currently you have three. Even in development that is not a good thing. Also, what type of effect are you looking for. Easing determines how an animation occurs, but doesn't let us know what type of animation you want.

Comment: Thanks Doug. I appreciate it the comments. haha  I know I only need one copy of jQuery. Like I said, don't mind my mess :) I'd like this kind of easing on my bottom menu.

http://www.dynamicdrive.com/style/csslibrary/item/jquery_drop_line_menu/

Hope that helps. Like I said, I'm pretty much the biggest jquery noob and hoping to learn how this all works by finishing my own work and working backwards.

Thanks again.

Comment: Why develop a menu? This has been somewhat done to death. There are many plugins for this that will avoid you reinventing all the browser specific code.

Comment: Thanks cletus. Could you point me in the right direction?

Comment: I've used superfish before. It does a pretty good job: http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/ and there are others.

Comment: Great, thank you cletus. I'll take a look at superfish.

Comment: Just realized how EASY superfish was to edit. You Cletus are the man! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the asnwer thanks to cletus. Superfish will work perfect for my situation and will be easy to implement using a few simple CSS changes.